# How to predict optimal reachability of outbound calls?

Tags: probability, modeling

I'm trying to build a model to predict the optimal (clock) time for a outbound call to a person. The goal is to maximize reachability. The historical data contains some input variables (age, profession, sex, etc), the time of the call-attempt and the indicator whether the person has been contacted or not. I have to deliver a probability for every time-window for each person.

For example, for here are two time windows for "Person A":

> 08:00-10:00: $p(reachability) = 76\%$
>
> 11:00-13:00: $p(reachability) = 40\%$ and so on.

The possibilities I've considered are:

1. Building a model for each time-window (something like a decision tree with first split on "time-window").
2. Reducing the data only to reached persons and building a multinomial model.
3. Building a naive bayes classifier?

What would be the best approach?